# Having multiple registration form with fosuser bundle

Tags: symfony, registration, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms, fosuserbundle

I'm new to symfony2 & I'm writing an application that requires to have 2 different user types.
one is normal user & the other is the one which has same fields as user plus some other extra fields.
we design it with foreign key & one-to-one relationship.
Now I don't understand how to build two different registration forms with the functionality of FOSUserBundle.i mean i don't know how to override RegistrationController for this purpose

thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [PugxMultiUserBundle](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle). I think that is exactly what you are after, I have been using it for one of my projects and it works like a charm!

Comment: yes.i saw that!but it extends the user class which i think means that all the user feature will be duplicated in the other user(second type).. >>thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use RollerworksMultiUserBundle:
https://github.com/rollerworks/RollerworksMultiUserBundle